# Jenkins API request using Curl

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to make a request to the Jenkins API. However, I always get a 401 unauthorized error. I have tried all permutations of requests using Curl - including sending the API token and Crumb. The Jenkins is hosted on a DEV server and not on my local. I have CSRF protection enabled on Jenkins. Could this be a CORS issue or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Trigger Jenkins build with parameters using API token

Variables

**UserName** is the user with permission to execute jobs

**UserTokenValue** is the token key assigned to UserName.

**JobTokenValue** is the token key assigned to the job to allow remote execution.

1. **Create User Token** - if jenkins instance requires authorization to execute jobs then user token will be required or the error "missing bread crumb trail" may appear.

   Login to Jenkins

   Click username in top right corner

   Click configure

   Click add token

   Capture the UserTokenValue. Note:Token id will not be needed going forward.

**Optional** - verify token assigned to user.
*Command* `curl -v -u <user>:<userTokenValue> <jenkins>/user/<user>/api/json`

*Example* `curl -v -u john:11bc70579c86512be9a4356127640abfda http://jenkins.dv.local:8080/user/john/api/json`

2. **Enable Jenkins Job to "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"**

   Locate Jenkins job and click Configure

   Scroll to the "Build Triggers" section and enable the checkbox "Trigger builds remotely"

   Enter a secret "Authentication Token" in the text box. The Token is required to execute this specific job remotely. Use "SuperSecret"

   Because the Token is set in this one job configuration, that value will only allow this one job to execute remotely.

   Use the same value for all jobs if you like but there is no way to manage the JobTokenValue Globally that I know of.
3. **Execute job with parameters using Curl POST**

   Your values will vary...

   JenkinsUrl     : https://jenkins.dv.local:8080

   UserName       : john

   UserTokenValue : 115e46b2109bda095cc070b6347dafe585

   JobTokenValue  : SuperSecret

*Command*

```
curl -X POST <JenkinsUrl>/job/test/build -user <UserName>:<UserTokenValue> --data token=<JobTokenValue> --data parm1Name=parm1Value --data parm2Name="Parm2Value with spaces"
```

*Example*

```
curl -X POST http://jenkins.dv.local:8080/job/MyRemoteJob/buildWithParameters --user john:115e46b2109bda095cc070b6347dafe585 --data token=SuperSecret --data TEST_PLAN_KEY=QTAK-1040 --data BROWSER="Chrome (headless)"
```

Answer (score 0):

401 probably means your username/pass are incorrect.

This works for me:
`curl -v -X GET "http://$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/json" --user $USERNAME:$USERPASS`

If there is a CORS issue, use https://plugins.jenkins.io/cors-filter/.

Comment: Hi I am using ntlm for my credentials because that is how my organisation has setup the environment.
The issue i'am having now is that I need a "Crumb" from the Jenkins API in my request. However, when request for one (using my API token) I get a 403 invalid crumb? How can I get a Crumb if I need to provide one?